# Python Function to use row numbers in a function

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

```py
df['New Column'][0] = chi2_contingency([[df['A'][0],df['B'][0]],[df['C'][0],df['D'][0]]])
df['New Column'][1] = chi2_contingency([[df['A'][1],df['B'][1]],[df['C'][1],df['D'][1]]])
df['New Column'][2] = chi2_contingency([[df['A'][2],df['B'][2]],[df['C'][2],df['D'][2]]])
df['New Column'][3] = chi2_contingency([[df['A'][3],df['B'][3]],[df['C'][3],df['D'][3]]])
```

Guys, how can I write a function which replaces the code above? I need to update row numbers (range is 0 - 50)?

Comment: Something like `df['New column'] = df[['A','B','C','D']].apply(chi2_contingency, axis=1)` (or however chi2_contingency needs to receive each row) might be more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean that

```
for x in range(50):
    df['New Column'][x] = chi2_contingency([[df['A'][x],df['B'][x]],[df['C'][x],df['D'][x]]])
```

Comment: That's going to be a _lot_ of SettingWithCopyWarnings though.

Comment: Yes, I've got several SettingWithCopyWarnings. But other than that it is working fine.